# Can any one Help me out in Drawing a rectangle in an image?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, bitmap

Guys I a new programmer in C++, please can you help me out in writing a program for drawing a blue colored rectangle in Visual C++ in a bitmap 24bit colored image without using OpenCV.
Also in VS C++ I'm not able to get a header graphics.h instead what shud i use.
I have to draw a rectangle in the image not the line
Here is my code in VS-C++ which only shows a black line at the bottom:

```
void copy_Header(FILE *,FILE *);

void main()
{

    FILE *src; int offset; int width, height;
    fopen_s(&src,"jaguar.bmp","rb");
    FILE *dest;
    fopen_s(&dest,"rect_image.bmp","wb");

    fseek(src,10,SEEK_SET);
    fread(&offset,4,1,src);

    fseek(src,18,SEEK_SET);
    fread(&width,4,1,src);

    fseek(src,22,SEEK_SET);
    fread(&height,4,1,src);

    copy_Header(src,dest);

    fseek(src,offset,SEEK_SET);
    fseek(dest,offset,SEEK_SET);
    unsigned char x=(unsigned char)fgetc(src);
    double r,g,b,z[3];
    int i;
    unsigned char ch[3];
    b=ch[0]=fgetc(src);
    g=ch[1]=fgetc(src);
    r=ch[2]=fgetc(src);
    for (int j=0;j<4;j++)
    {
        for(; offset<width; offset++)
        {
            z[0]=b;
            z[1]=0;
            z[2]=0;
            fputc(z[0],dest);
            fputc(z[1],dest);
            fputc(z[2],dest);
        }
    }

    fseek(src,4096,SEEK_SET);
    fseek(dest,4096,SEEK_SET);
    unsigned char y= (unsigned char)fgetc(src);
    while(!feof(src))
    {
        fputc(y,dest);
        y=(unsigned char)fgetc(src);
    }
    fclose(src);
    fclose(dest);
    puts("Image Copied");
    _getch();

}

void copy_Header(FILE *srcImage,FILE *dstImage)
{
    unsigned char *ptrc= (unsigned char *)malloc(54*sizeof(char));

    fseek(srcImage,0,SEEK_SET);
    fseek(dstImage,0,SEEK_SET);

    fread(ptrc,54,1,srcImage);
    fwrite(ptrc,54,1,dstImage);
}
```

Thanx in advance.
image size is of 1024 by 1024 and is 24 bit bitmap file.

Comment: Which part of code you show is an attempt to draw anything?

Comment: Sir I have edited my post and m getting problem in the below code and here I tried to attempt for a line not for the rectangle. But I need to know about the rectangle too. Kindly Help me out.

Comment: Sir I am Not a software engg or an IT professional. I was curious about learning the programming in VS-C++. Since m new to this blog so i have no idea of that. But one should help a person who is a new comer not decrease his/her morality. Thanx for you gr8 support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's break the problem.

**First problem**: how do you relate a pixel coordinate to its position in a file?

In other words, given a RGB pixel with coordinates (x,y), where is it located on the file?

Let's consider that it has WIDTH width and HEIGHT height. Since it has 3 channels - Red, Green, and Blue - and considering each channel has 1 byte, each pixel will have 3 bytes in size. A BMP file is just a matrix of pixels, organized line by line, so each line will have then 3*WIDTH bytes.

The x coordinate will then tell how many lines will be skipped, and y will point to the pixel in the current line. In other words:

```
seek_position= x*(3*WIDTH) + 3*y
```

With this relation, you can now write a function like

```
int mat2seek(int x,int y){
    //converts a xy coordinate system to seek position
    return x*(3*WIDTH) + 3*y + BMP_HEADER_SIZE;
}
```

where BMP_HEADER_SIZE is self explaining

**Second problem**: now that you know how to convert a (x,y) coordinate system to seek system, what is the algorithm of drawing a rectangle?

Such algorithm is a lot easier to make in (x,y) coordinate than seek coordinates:

```
for (int x = xini; x< xend; x++)
    for (int y=yini; y<yend; y++){
        int seek=mat2seek(x,y);
        //do the magic...
    }
```

Comment: Can you tell me that where should I put this function code and how could i apply it in my code. It would be gr8 help from you sir.